# using a dropdown list in mvc4

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC for the first time. I have understood the logic but i am facing problems              while implementing my code. I want to show a dropdownlist with following values.
In controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> ListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                ListItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = "1",
                    Text = "---Select---",
                });

                ListItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = "2",
                    Text = " What is your nationality?",
                });

                ListItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = "3",
                    Text = " What is your birth place?",
                });

                model.Sec_Que = new SelectList(ListItems, "Value", "Text");
                return View(model);
```

Now, i would like to use the selected value and add it to database.
In Model i have the following code:

```
[Display(Name = "Security Question")]
    public SelectList Sec_Que { get; set; }
```

In view i wrote:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sec_Que, Model.Sec_Que)
```

I am getting an error, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' How do i fix it? Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that `model` is not null?

Comment: @vonv. i am passing parameter to my controller like this,

Comment: `public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)` so i think model is not null

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the dropdown need to be initialized

```
[Display(Name = "Security Question")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sec_Que { get; set; }
```

Also add a backing field to represent the selected value in the view model class

```
public string selectedText{ get; set; }
```

finally do this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedText, Model.Sec_Que)
```

Comment: But this won't solve the issue `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, wouldn't it?

Comment: The error is still there. 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: how are you instantiating your model object.are u doing that in your controller?i dont see that part.i see model.sec_que but where the model object is created?